# jQuery blockUI dialog opens when go back in browser

Tags: jquery, asp.net, blockui, jquery-blockui

I have a jquery dialog and when I open and close it, go to another page, and after that, go back with the browser go back button, the dialog is showed again. This is happening in Chrome and IE and not in Firefox. What can I modified of the dialog? Thanks!

```
<td class ="approval-img"><asp:ImageButton runat="server" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("aux_approvalId")%>'  OnClick="getApprovalID_approve" ToolTip="Approve" ImageUrl="/Images/Approve.png" /></td>

 protected void getApprovalID_approve(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   .....
        string script = "OpenApprovalDialog();";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "", script, true);
    }
```

These are the functions for open/close the dialog:

```
function OpenApprovalDialog() {
    $.blockUI({ message: $('#approval-form'), baseZ: 10000 });
    $('#approval-form').parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
    return false;
};
$('#btnCancelApprove').click(function () {
        $.unblockUI();
        $("#approval-form").parent().detach();
        return false;
    });
```

And the dialog that is opened:

```
<div id="approval-form" style="display: none; cursor: default" title="Approve">
   <div class="approve-change">
 <ul>
    <li>
      <p><label>Approve change:  </label><label>Reason</label></p>
      <textarea id="txtReasonApprove" runat="server" cols="1" rows="1" class="required"></textarea><br />
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>
        <button id="btnCancelApprove" class="blue-problem">Cancel</button>
        <asp:Button ID="btnApprove" runat="server" CssClass="blue-problem" Text="Approve" ToolTip = "Approve"  OnClick="ApproveChange_Click"/>
      </span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is blockUI, not JQuery dialog

Comment: Would it be ok to change OnClick="getApprovalID_approve" with OnClick="OpenApprovalDialog()" ???

Comment: Ok, I'll modify the title now. With Openapprovaldialog() I get the exception: No overload for method 'ApproveChange_Click' takes 0 arguments

Comment: Sorry, try this OnClientClick="OpenApprovalDialog()" this will execute client side script

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ivan, with OnClick="getApprovalID_approve" OnClientClick="OpenApprovalDialog()" the dialog is not opened if I don't include Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "", script, true); And I'm in the same position, the dialog is opened when go back in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Set this script before leaving page.

```
  <script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        $.unblockUI();
    };
</script>
```